# Suppress blank lines in Word when using IF Field codes

Tags: ms-word, word-field

I am using the following to conditionally output text in an MS Word document:

```
  { IF { DOCPROPERTY manual_version } = 1 "Version 1" "" \* MERGEFORMAT }
  { IF { DOCPROPERTY manual_version } = 2 "Version 2" "" \* MERGEFORMAT }
  { IF { DOCPROPERTY manual_version } = 3 "Version 3" "" \* MERGEFORMAT }
```

If `manual_version` is set to 3, then the text "Version 3". The previous IF field codes aren't supposed to output anything but they output a blank line. How do I change that?

Comment: In the code posted it appears that each IF field is in its own line (paragraph). Put them all in the *same* "line". One following directly on the other.

Comment: Oh Lord, it was that easy! Thank you very much Cindy!

Comment: You're welcome :-) Please note that questions of this nature really are more on-topic on the Super User site. Stack Overflow is for programming topics, which in the case of fields means more how to fix field code problems.

Answer (score 0):

Your entire field code construction could be reduced to:

```
{DOCPROPERTY manual_version \# "'Version '0;;"}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The example I posted isn't really representative of what I am trying to achieve in the sense that the text changes drastically between different versions.

Comment: In that case, kindly make your examples representative of what you're trying to achieve. All you've done in this case is wasted my time...